# routerlink accept string params

Tags: javascript, frontend, angular2-routing, angular

```
...
  path: ':category/:page',
...
```

```
<a [routerLink]="[category.attributes.alias-name, 1]"> 
{{category.attributes.name}} </a>
```

First param of routerLink in browser is NaN. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As point out by Bougarfaoui El houcine, the expression `category.attributes.alias-name` is interprete as a substration. And something minus `undefined` = `Nan`.
So, try using this code to get rid of your error

```
<a [routerLink]="[category.attributes['alias-name'], '1']">
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
<a [routerLink]="[category.attributes.alias-name, '1']">
```

Comment: I mean category.attributes.alias-name is NaN in browser query url

Comment: Do you get shown anything when you add `<div>{{category.attributes.alias-name}}</div>` to your components template? I can't know what `category.attributes.alias-name` is supposed to return and if it does that or not.

Comment: The params should be only string values.if the URL is updated like http://localhost8201/category/page=1.Then you can read it from activated route

Comment: @Vignesh got u. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a [routerLink]="[category.attributes['alias-name'], '1']">
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.